Power automate flow - cached data issue
In my flow I'm extracting data from excel file located on sharepoint and then I'm inserting it to sql server database, after that file is moved to another location. First execution is working fine, but when I'm put some other file in the same sharepoint location (with the same name) it is using old file (but file itself - opened directly via sharepoint has new data). Is there any way to fix it?

Can you share more from your Power Automate solution?

I would recommend using variables for Excel File and Table names instead of hard-coding in the Get Rows step as shown in the screenshots below.
No Issues found with the following steps:

Uploaded a test excel file with a table of rows in it
Execute the Power Automate manually
Power Automate steps can save the data to SQL. But, in my test, it just
output by using Compose
Manually Move the Excel file from Library A to Library B
Manually updated the data in the excel file and then uploaded to Library A
(same file name and table, but data was changed)
Execute the same Power Automate





Great, it helped.
